# Turn a string inside out

Tags: code-golf, string, balanced-string

A balanced string is a string of parentheses `()` so that every parenthesis is can be matched with another one.  More rigorously they are the strings spanned by this grammar:

```
S → (S)S | ε
```

We can turn a string "inside out" by:

- Switching all occurrences of `(` and `)` with each other
- Moving characters from the front of the string to the back until the string is balanced again.

---

Lets do an example.

We start with the balanced string:

```
(()(())())
```

We then switch the parens to make

```
))())(()((
```

Then move characters from the front of the string to the back of the string until the string is balanced.

```
))())(()((
)())(()(()
())(()(())
))(()(())(
)(()(())()
(()(())())
```

Thats our result!

---

Note that some strings can be turned inside out in multiple ways, for example the string

```
(()())
```

When turned inside out can be either:

```
()(())
```

or

```
(())()
```

However every string [has at least one solution](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38554888#38554888).

## Task

Write a program to take a balanced string as input and output that string turned inside out.  In cases where there may be multiple valid outputs you need only output one of them.  You may use a different brace type (`<>`,`[]` or `{}`) if you so wish.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) competition so you should aim to minimize your size of your source code, as measured by bytes.

### Test Cases

```
(()())     -> ()(()), (())()
(()(())()) -> (()(())())
((())())() -> (()(()()))
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there is always a solution?

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, I have proven this.  If you would like to see the proof, feel free to ping me in chat.

Comment: Thanks. It is sufficient for me to know that. Maybe you should write it into the challenge, otherwise you would need to define what to output if no solution

Comment: [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/114219/balance-the-brackets?rq=1)

Answer (score 9):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>124</s> <s>120</s> <s>119</s> <s>117</s> <s>113</s> <s>110</s> <s>109</s> <s>106</s> <s>105</s> <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 98 bytes

*4 bytes saved thanks to bartavelle!*

*3 bytes saved thanks to Zgarb*

*1 byte saved thanks to Peter Taylor*

Here's a solution I worked out in Haskell.  Its <s>ok right now</s> pretty good thanks to some help I received, but I'm looking to make this shorter, so feedback/suggestions are appreciated.

```hs
until(!0)g.map d
_!1=1<0
('(':a)!x=a!(x-1)
(_:a)!x=a!(x+1)
_!_=1>0
g(a:b)=b++[a]
d '('=')'
d _='('
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYtBC4IwGIbv@xWbBvuGGO46@gKJkCDKS6eKMTFNmiJlIES/fU0v8T6H5zm8d/N63Kx1nzik@/SQndJsSzd5TsP4Syq8uHc3NBZYIupla3paEs0kylVCgANXRrARDYMxloKA/nfkWzONcp2QGowqBBZRdDZXUlJ/RC64N43eXWuaTqndEQSZFPtn0w2LKgAQE34zswTuBw)

### Explanation

This program defines 4 functions,  the first `(!)` determines if a string is balanced.  Its defined as follows:

```hs
_!1=1<0
('(':a)!x=a!(x-1)
(_:a)!x=a!(x+1)
_!_=1>0
```

This check assumes that the input has an equal number of open and close parens thanks to a suggestion from Peter Taylor.

The next `g` will rotate the string once.

```hs
g(a:b)=b++[a]
```

Then we have `d` which simply takes a paren and mirrors it

```hs
d '('=')'
d _='('
```

Finally we have the function we are concerned with. Here we use a pointfree representation of `until(!0)g` composed with `map d`, which maps `d` to the input and applies `g` until the result is balanced.  This is the exact process described in the question.

```hs
until(!0)g.map d
```

Comment: You can scrap a few bytes with `g x@(a:b)|x!0=x|1>0=g$b++[a]` and removing the parens for `d '('=')'`.

Comment: @bartavelle Removing the parens for `d` causes a compiler error, believe me I've tried.  But the first suggestion is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: You can definitively drop those parens. Also, as your "f" function can be expressed in point-free style, you are allowed not to count the `f=` part. You can use `CPP` to make it fit in `tio`, like [THAT](https://tio.run/##RYtBC4IwHMXv@xSbCtsQY7uO/pFESBDlpZOJTEyTVKQ6DLLPvqaXeO/w@z14d/163LrOfiIfH@NTcomTPd6lKfajL6rhaptVr0dcoSwnBgSAQQWRINcCMcqo0tzNmjATSY5Y8ffQeYPNlmlV8skQAWaSGwFNUIZhpnNUYfcHyqmjAhwj2@t2UOpwZhzNCOOzHd5B7THG57osXcCzPw "Haskell – Try It Online") !

Comment: @bartavelle I see, I need to add a space if I remove the parens.  Thanks!

Comment: You can save another byte in `!` because you don't need to handle cases where the string has an unequal number of open and close parentheses, so you can swap the first two cases and have `_!1=1<0` `[]!_=0<1`

Comment: Use `until` to shorten `g`: [TIO](https://tio.run/##RYtBC4IwGIbv@xWbBvuGGO46@gKJkCDKS6eKMTFNmiJlIES/fU0v8T6H5zm8d/N63Kx1nzik@/SQndJsSzd5TsP4Syq8uHc3NBZYIupla3paEs0kylVCgANXRrARDYMxloKA/nfkWzONcp2QGowqBBZRdDZXUlJ/RC64N43eXWuaTqndEQSZFPtn0w2LKgAQE34zswTuBw)

Comment: I think there should be a decent saving by making `d` map `'('` to `(-1)` and anything else to `1`, and then the two longest cases of `!` can be combined to `(i:a)!x=a!(x+i)`. The top level structure then needs reworking to push `map d` into the `until` condition, and I have to run so I haven't got time right now to figure out what combinators are required to glue it all together.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I've been playing around with it and I haven't been able to figure a way to make it work.  The main drawback is you need to convert back to parens.  Originally I had intended for more lenient IO that would have made golfs like this possible but I forgot to include them and, but I don't want to abuse my power as OP.

Comment: @PeterTaylor [I have this but it requires `import Data.Char` which ends up costing it bytes.](https://tio.run/##FYxPC4IwHIbv@xRTO2wMh7t0GE4QCwmivHSqkJ@VOvIfa4EQfXZrPJeX54Wnhdfz0XXLJwzwPj3kpzTf4qwocBB@ke6n0Vi8AQs8a8GgWl2WHiZyaw0na8Eo5e/B6o54EW24e/42pHw0d4pKTygRR4hoCdSbFXhkZtr5UokkQg0BWVFVMXaG6z@rByl3R0KRm2oyerCr2o/jxJH4yw8 "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: Yes, I realised that later. Sorry.

Answer (score 7):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), <s>12</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
↔]»:l{Ƨ()øŗ
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUyMTk0JTVEJUJCJTNBbCU3QiV1MDFBNyUyOCUyOSVGOCV1MDE1Nw__,inputs=JTI4JTI4JTI5JTI4JTI4JTI5JTI5JTI4JTI5JTI5)

Explanation:

```
↔            mirror characters
 ]           do ... while the top of stack is truthy
  »            put the last letter at the start
   :           duplicate it
    l{         length times do
      Ƨ()        push "()"
         ø       push ""
          ŗ      replace ["()" with ""]
             if the string left on stack is empty (aka all matched parentheses could be removed), then stop the while loop
```

Note: `l{` could be replaced with [(](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/P5ParserV0_12/data/charDefs.txt#L202) for 10 bytes, but, sadly, it isn't implemented.

Comment: Are you sure that mirroring the characters works?  I don't know exactly what that means but my intuition tells me that it also reverses the order of the characters which, I don't think would work.

Comment: @Olmman It _was_ intended to reverse the characters, but doesn't (which saves a byte here!). It's on V0.13s line-up to change trough. [Example](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUyMTk0,inputs=aGVsbG8lMjglMjk_)

Answer (score 5):

### CJam (20 chars)

```
q1f^0X${~_}%_:e>#)m<
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q1f%5E0X%24%7B~_%7D%25_%3Ae%3E%23)m%3C&input=(()(())()))

or for the same char count

```
q1f^_,,{0W$@<~}$W=m<
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q1f%5E_%2C%2C%7B0W%24%40%3C~%7D%24W%3Dm%3C&input=(()(())()))

#### Dissection

The two versions have a common header and footer

```
q1f^    e# Read input and toggle least significant bit of each character
        e# This effectively swaps ( and )

m<      e# Stack: swapped_string index
        e# Rotates the string to the left index characters
```

Then the bit in the middle obviously calculates how far it's necessary to rotate. Both of them use evaluation and rely on `(` being the CJam decrement operator and `)` being the increment operator.

```
0X$     e# Push 0 and a copy of the swapped string
{~_}%   e# Map: evaluate one character and duplicate top of stack
        e# The result is an array of the negated nesting depth after each character
_:e>    e# Copy that array and find its maximum value
#       e# Find the first index at which that value occurs
)       e# Increment
```

vs

```
_,,     e# Create array [0 1 ... len(swapped_string)-1]
{       e# Sort with mapping function:
  0W$@  e#   Rearrange stack to 0 swapped_string index
  <~    e#   Take first index chars of swapped_string and evaluate
}$      e# The result is an array of indices sorted by the negated nesting depth
W=      e# Take the last one
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>111</s> 105 bytes

(Saved 2 bytes thanks to @CraigAyre, 2 bytes thanks to @PeterTaylor, 2 bytes thanks to @Shaggy.)

```
s=>(r=[...s].map(c=>'()'[c<')'|0])).some(_=>r.push(r.shift(i=0))&&!r.some(c=>(i+=c<')'||-1)<0))&&r.join``
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
s=>(
  r=[...s].map(c=>'()'[c<')'|0]),  //switch "(" and ")"
  r.some(_=>(
    r.push(r.shift(i=0)),          //move last element to beginning of array, initialize i
    !r.some(c=>(i+=c<')'||-1)<0)   //check if balanced (i should never be less than 0)
  )),
  r.join``
)
```

**Test cases:**

```js
let f=

s=>(r=[...s].map(c=>'()'[c<')'|0])).some(_=>r.push(r.shift(i=0))&&!r.some(c=>(i+=c<')'||-1)<0))&&r.join``

console.log(f('(()())'));      // ()(())
console.log(f('(()(())())'));  // (()(())())
console.log(f('((())())()'));  // (()(()()))
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>46</s> 38 bytes

```
T`()`)(
(.*?)(((\()|(?<-4>\)))+)$
$2$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPyRBQzNBU4NLQ0/LXlNDQyNGQ7NGw95G18QuRlNTU1tThUvFSMXw/38NDU0NTU0uEAWkIUwIQ0MTAA) Link includes test cases. Edit: Saved 8 bytes with help from @MartinEnder. The first stage simply transposes the parentheses, while the second stage looks for longest suffix that's a valid balanced prefix, which apparently is a sufficient condition for the rotation to be fully balanced. The balancing is detected using balancing groups. The construct `((\()|(?<-4>\)))+` matches any number of `(`s plus any number of `)`s as long as we have already (`<-4>`) seen as many `(`s. Since we're only looking for a valid prefix we don't have to match the remaining `)`s.

Comment: Normally, instead of repeating both parentheses, you just put them in an alternation, which saves a byte `((\()|(?<-2>\)))`. But your attempt just inspired me to find a completely new approach that saves another two: `(?<-1>(\()*\))+`. This will certainly come in handy in the future, so thank you. :)

Comment: It's even shorter to determine the rotation by matching the first suffix through which you can reach the end of the string without getting a negative stack depth: https://tio.run/##JcaxDkAwFIbRvc9xJd9fIcEqOnoBY4caDBaDeP@LdDrnPp7z2r1hLb4VVESgj0mQ5m5ayChmqc1EU7DRBncQUvj5rK1BLw

Comment: @MartinEnder I originally tried an alternation but I couldn't get it to work at the time, but I fail to see how `(?<-1>(\()*\))+` even works, since it seems to want to pop from the `1` stack before having actually matched anything...

Comment: @MartinEnder As it happens, the alternation version seems to be golfer when it comes to matching balanced prefixes.

Comment: The actual popping happens at the end of the group, not the beginning. Good point with the alternation to avoid the duplicate `\(*` though.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 78 bytes

```
""<>{"(",")"}[[2ToCharacterCode@#-81//.x_/;Min@Accumulate@x<0:>RotateLeft@x]]&
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>110</s> 108 bytes

```php
for($s=$argn;;$p?die(strtr($s,"()",")(")):$s=substr($s,1).$s[$i=0])for($p=1;$p&&$c=$s[$i++];)$p-=$c<")"?:-1;
```

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [test it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/64042062d19ae3ce2651f9b367ee6e084aa1dda7).

**breakdown**

```php
for($s=$argn;               # import input
    ;                       # infinite loop
    $p?die(strtr($s,"()",")(")) # 2. if balanced: invert, print and exit
    :$s=substr($s,1).$s[$i=0]   #    else: rotate string, reset $i to 0
)                               # 1. test balance:
    for($p=1;                   # init $p to 1
        $p&&$c=$s[$i++];)       # loop through string while $p is >0
        $p-=$c<")"?:-1;             # increment $p for ")", decrement else
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>112</s> <s>103</s> 101 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to @Mr.Xcoder*

```python
k=y=input().translate(' '*40+')(')
while k:
 k=y=y[1:]+y[0]
 for _ in y:k=k.replace('()','')
print(y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7BCsIwEETv@Yqll@xaKRU9FfIX3kqRElcaEtIQUzRfH1PqaeYwb2ZCTsvqr0WvT1ZN0xSrsjI@bAmpS3H2bzcnRgnydOtbSShJfBbjGOwgYA/n8TJMbR77ScBrjfAA4yEPVtkucnCzrjSSPMtKhmh8wkylLv1r7nHj2gT8ZY37CyqIhERil6qHPQzSDw)

Comment: [101 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY7BCsIwEETv@Yqll@xaKRU9FfIX3kqRElcaEtIQUzRfH1PqaeYwb2ZCTsvqr0WvT1ZN0xSrsjI@bAmpS3H2bzcnRgnydOtbSShJfBbjGOwgYA/n8TJMbR77ScBrjfAA4yEPVtkucnCzrjSSPMtKhmh8wkylLv1r7nHj2gT8ZY37CyqIhERil6qHPQzSDw)? Not sure it works

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, 62 bytes

```matlab
@(s)")("(x=hankel(s,shift(s,1))-39)(all(cumsum(2*x'-3)>=0)',:)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcxBDkAwFEXRvZj0PakEHZFUbOVHCFE1@Cp2Xx3d0bn38si75jxDWREVPr9LPNcAtbof21PakY0bCAkBS7o0XejrzzSOk29p7MgsUYsFwXLJPw)

A function that takes the string as input and prints all results.

**Explanation:**

```matlab
           hankel(a,shift(a,1))                                % generate a matrix of n*n where n= length(s) and its rows contain incresing circulraly shifted s
         x=...                 -39                             % convert matrix of "(" and ")" to a mtrix of 1 and 2
    ")("(x                        )                            % switch the parens
                                               2*x'-3          % convert [1 2] to [-1 1]
                                        cumsum(      )         % cumulative sum along the rows
                                    all(              >=0)'    % if all >=0
                                   (                       ,:) % extract the desired rows
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>35</s> 30 bytes

*Golfed a new approach thanks to @Adám*

```apl
1⌽⍣{2::0⋄1∊⍎⍕1,¨⍺}')('['()'⍳⎕]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKPd8b/ho569j3oXVxtZWRk86m4xfNTR9ai371HvVEOdQyse9e6qVdfUUI9W19BUf9S7@VHf1FiQtv@OXOoaGpoamprqXFAmkI3gQjhAPQA)

Golfing is in progress.

#### Explanation

```apl
'()'⍳⎕              Find the index of each character of the input in the string '()'
                    (this is 1-indexed, so an input of '(())()' would give 1 1 2 2 1 2)
')('[...]           Find the index of the vector in the string ')('
                    This essentially swaps ')'s with '('s and vice versa
⍣                   On this new string, do:
 1⌽                   rotate it one to the left
                    Until this results in 1:
 1,¨⍺                 Concatenate each element of the argument with a 1
                      This inserts 1 one before each parenthesis
 ⍕                    Stringify it
 ⍎                    And evaluate it, if the parentheses are balanced, this produces no errors
 1∊                   Check if 1 belongs to evaluated value
                      If the parentheses were not matches during ⍎, this causes a syntax error
 2::0                 This catches a syntax error and returns 0
                      Essentially this code checks if the brackets are balanced or not
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 97 bytes

```
f=(s,t=s,u=t.replace(')(',''))=>u?t==u?f(s.slice(1)+s[0]):f(s,u):s.replace(/./g,c=>c<')'?')':'(')
```

Works by recursively rotating the input string until its transpose is balanced, then transposing it.

Comment: Simply beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 99 bytes

```python
r=[0];S=''
for c in input():b=c>'(';r+=[r[-1]+2*b-1];S+=')('[b]
n=r.index(min(r))
print S[n:]+S[:n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcWxCgIxDADQvV/RLYlF0Rtb4k90DF16KnYwV0IP9OvrwYPXf@O96TKnsVxLygzgXpv51Tc99H0gxcrrHRCSBRaT862E5VSPUg4MhCC1OGW7NH08v/hpikbkujUdPovGErJELXMCIiER/AE)

### In function form for easy test cases:

### [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 108 bytes

```python
def f(s):
 r=[0];S=''
 for c in s:b=c>'(';r+=[r[-1]+2*b-1];S+=')('[b]
 n=r.index(min(r))
 return S[n:]+S[:n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY69DoJAEIT7e4rtdlfQKOWRo@QFrrxcw1@8woUsmOjTI0hMrGa@Zr6Z3st9lGJdu36AgWa2BtSFayy9QzQwjAotJIHZNq6tkLDUzAUN51vMilOzRekzh0wYmmhAnF6SdP2LHklImbe5fnmqgA9iY@aDlfiV1Yds0iQLzDm6CvP9gDE1IRETM/Kvb/DHB9HO6wc)

This uses a slightly different approach - instead of recursively rotating the string, if we think of the parens as incrementing and decrementing some balance counter, then a balanced string must never have a total sum of increments - decrements that is less than 0.

So we take

```python
(()(())())
```

invert the parens:

```python
))())(()((
```

and convert it to a list of sums of increments/decrements:

```python
[-1,-2,-1,-2,-3,-2,-1,-2,-1,0]
```

-3 is the minimum at index 4 (zero based); so we want to shift by that index+1. This guarantees that the cumulative increment/decrement will never be less than 0; and will sum to 0.

Comment: On my phone so I can't test, but could you do `r=0,` instead of `r=[0]`?

Comment: If you're going with @Cyoce's suggestion, you will need to replace `r+=[r[-1]+2*b-1]` with `r+=r[-1]+2*b-1,` as well

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 118 bytes

```
#(loop[s(map{\(\)\)\(}%)](let[s(conj(vec(rest s))(first s))](if(some neg?(reductions +(map{\( 1\) -1}s)))(recur s)s)))
```

Returns a sequence of characters, so I'd call it like this:

```
(apply str (f "(()(())())"))
; "(()(())())"
```

First flips brackets, then loops as long as the cumulative sum of bracket count goes negative at some point of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), 82 bytes

```
,[++[->->++<<]-[--->+>-<<]>-->+[-[-<<+>>>>+<<]],]+[<<]>>>[.[-]>>]<[<<]<[<<]>>[.>>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYlBCoBADAO/s0s3@4LSj4QeVBBE8CD4/tpqKGQ6We/luPZnOyMGRQiDiag6CCQakq2IaVTFMrX7cGFtZpxEtmv9@kvOFBGttd6/ewE)

#### Explanation

With each character read, a counter is modified as follows:

- The counter starts at 0.
- After each `)`, the counter increases by 1.
- After each `(`, the counter decreases by 1, unless the counter was 0, in which case the counter is unchanged.

Each prefix is a valid suffix of a balanced string (after inversion) if and only if this counter is 0.  This code uses the longest such prefix to form the output.

```
,[                   Take input and start main loop
                     The cell one space right is the output cell (0 at this point),
                     and two spaces right is a copy of the previous counter value
  ++                 Add 2 to input
  [->->++<<]         Negate into output cell, and add twice to counter
  -[--->+>-<<]       Add 85 to output cell, and subtract 85 from counter
  >-->+              Subtract 2 from output cell and add 1 to counter
                     The output cell now has (81-input), and the counter has been increased by (2*input-80)
  [-[-<<+>>>>+<<]]   If the counter is nonzero, decrement and copy
,]
+[<<]                Go to the last position at which the counter is zero
>>>                  Go to following output character
[.[-]>>]             Output from here to end, clearing everything on the way
                     (Only the first one needs to be cleared, but this way takes fewer bytes)
<[<<]                Return to the same zero
<[<<]>>              Go to beginning of string
[.>>]                Output remaining characters
```